# Competitor o competitore?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Secondo il Treccani, il termine inglese non ha ancora trovato la legittimazione nei nostri dizionari, mentre il termine *competitore* sembra essere usato in contesti non economici.

- ***Quindi quale termine dovrei usare in italiano con significato di competitor nel senso economico/commerciale?***  "Concorrente" mi suona molto da quiz, e "antagonista" mi sembra un po' pesante come termine.

> - Tornando a “[competitor](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/articoli/paroledelleconomia/competitor.html)”, noteremo che il vocabolo non ha comunque ricevuto piena legittimazione dai dizionari dell’uso: il Sabatini-Coletti 2006 non lo registra, così come il Devoto-Oli 2006. Lo registrano invece lo Zingarelli 2007, il Grande dizionario della lingua italiana di De Mauro e il dizionario specialistico Neologismi quotidiani di Giovanni Adamo e Valeria Della Valle. Con una sorpresa aggiuntiva:
> - mentre, com’è ovvio, i nostri dizionari registrano “competitore” nel tradizionale significato di ‘rivale’, ‘concorrente’, sulla stampa, quando si tratta di argomenti economici e commerciali, non di rado viene usato “competitore” nel significato tecnico di “competitor”; mentre, come spesso succede, dal significato tecnico del termine si diramano numerosi usi di “competitore” con significato allargato ed estensivo di ‘concorrente, antagonista’. ***“Competitore” viene usato, insomma, in contesti diversi da quello economico-commerciale***.

Answer (score 11):

Il termine corretto è senza ombra di dubbio **concorrente**. L'accezione che ci interessa è definita dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/concorrente/) come «In commercio, chi gareggia con altri per conquistare un mercato o avere più clienti» etc.

E se restasse ancora qualche dubbio, basti pensare che il termine fa parte anche del linguaggio legale ed economico relativo al commercio e alle attività imprenditoriali: esiste un reato di “concorrenza sleale”, norme che regolano la concorrenza, studi che la indagano etc.

Comment: quindi forse per questo i dizionari sono restii ad adottare *competitor*? Un termine che  a me sembra essere sempre più usato.

Comment: @Josh61: La gente usa termini inglesi – a volte a sproposito, o pronunciandoli male – perché fa fico (il che in ambito sociolinguistico si formula più correttamente dicendo che l'inglese è percepito come una lingua di maggior prestigio). Vedi per esempio [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2015/05/25/esempi-itanglese/). Si potrebbe poi fare la discussa distinzione tra prestiti di necessità e prestiti di lusso etc. (e questo è senz'altro di lusso inutile), ma il discorso si farebbe lungo.

Comment: Finalmente. "Concorrente", da quanto tempo non sentivo questa semplice parola.

Comment: La Fiat contro chi compete o contro chi concorre?

Comment: Da non dimenticare la **concorrenza**, intesa come insieme dei concorrenti

Comment: @Josh61: la Fiat (FCA) **compete** con VW, Ford, etc... per il primato sul mercato. Nel caso, **concorre** allo sviluppo delle tecnologie del proprio mercato di riferimento.

Comment: @Riccardo               Quindi *competere e concorrere* hanno un uso diverso rispetto ai loro sostantivi.

Comment: Secondo me si. Io li uso in quelle accezioni e non sono scambiabili. Non ho il vocabolario sottomano per controllare se sia giusto.